# php imap_fetchbody strange encoding

Tags: php, imap

I have a little problem with imap_fetchbody. I accessed with the script below:

```
  $string= "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}";
  $mbox = imap_open($string.$_GET['f'], "mail@gmail.com", "password");
  $message = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$_GET['email'],'1.2');
```

Then I printed the $message content, and I got this:

```
 ATTENZIONE
 Il presente messaggio ed i suoi = allegati devono intendersi ad uso esclusivo dei suoi destinatari e sono = confidenziali. 
 Se ricevete questo messaggio per errore, Vi preghiamo = di cancellarlo, di distruggerne ogni copia e di informarci = immediatamente.
 Internet non garantisce l'integrit=E0 dei messaggi. = La scrivente declina pertanto ogni responsabilit=E0 in caso di = intercettazione o modifiche del presente = messaggio.
```

I know that E0 is equivalent tot à, and I could replace it in this case, but I also have some random = signs, and I can't remove them.

I'm trying to resolve the problem. I looked at the HTML, and I have this:

```
 <p =="" class="3DMsoNormal" style="3D'margin-bottom:12.0pt'">
     <span =="" style="3D'font-size:7.5pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#999999=" ;mso-fareast-language:it'="">
      ATTENZIONE<br>Il presente messaggio ed i suoi =
      allegati devono intendersi ad uso esclusivo dei suoi destinatari e sono =
      confidenziali. <br>Se ricevete questo messaggio per errore, Vi preghiamo =
      di cancellarlo, di distruggerne ogni copia e di informarci =
      immediatamente.<br>Internet non garantisce l'integrit=E0 dei messaggi. =
      La scrivente&nbsp;declina pertanto ogni responsabilit=E0 in caso di =
      intercettazione o modifiche del presente =
      messaggio.<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

That's pretty strange for HTML. In the HTML tag, I found this:

```
<html xmlns:v="3D&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml&quot;" =="" xmlns:o="3D&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office&quot;" xmlns:w="3D&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word&quot;" xmlns:m="3D&quot;http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml&quot;" xmlns="3D&quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40&quot;"><head><meta =="" http-equiv="3DContent-Type" content="3D&quot;text/html;" charset="3Diso-8859-1&quot;"><meta name="3DGenerator" content="3D&quot;Microsoft" word="14" (filtered="" medium)"="">
```

Does anybody have an idea how to make the = signs disappear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quoted-printable encoding.  Please search SO for related questions.